# Jenkinsfile doesn't recognize local bin

Tags: macos, mac-mini, path

I am trying to run `fastlane` commands using `Jenkinsfile` on Mac mini.

If I run `/usr/local/bin/fastlane -v` it shows the correct output. but if I just try with `fastlane -v` then I get

```
fastlane: command not found
```

`fastlane -v` works on Jenkins slave if I just ssh and run.

To debug this I tried to run `echo $PATH` through Jenkinsfile, got

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

If I ssh to jenkins Slave as `jenkins` user & run `echo $PATH`, I get

```
/Users/jenkins/.fastlane/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

Why is this difference ?

This is `plist` for jenkins agent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.jenkins.ci</string>
        <key>UserName</key>
        <string>jenkins</string>
        <key>SessionCreate</key>
        <true/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/bin/java</string>
          <string>-Djava.awt.headless=true</string>
      <string>-jar</string>
      <string>/Users/jenkins/agent.jar</string>
          <string>-jnlpUrl</string>
          <string>http://jenkins.example.com:8080/computer/jenkins2-slave3/slave-agent.jnlp</string>
          <string>-secret</string>
          <string>****************************</string>
          <string>-workDir</string>
          <string>/Users/jenkins/jenkins_slave/</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/jenkins/error.log</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/jenkins/stdout.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If running from launchd the OS runs the command directly and not through any shell. Also in this case it is running fastlane as root.

If from the terminal or ssh then you start a shell, sourcing your init files e.g. .zshenv .zshrc - Your additions to the path /Users/jenkins/.fastlane/bin:/usr/local/bin: will be in one of those shell files.

This is like running  from crontab on other Unixes. There is very little environment.

So solutions include any combination of these

1. use full paths to executables,
2. make launchd run a shell script that sets the environment and then call the executables
3. add environment variables to the .plist file (see EnvironmentVariables key) (I think PATH is not settable there but I might be wrong).

Also in this case add the username to the .plist see UserName key.

Comment: Adding `<key>EnvironmentVariables</key>` fixed it